# Controlling JFame from another class

Tags: java

I want to create a menu window, which will be part of a gui class.
The gui class is controlled from a Manager class. The problem is that when I press a button in the menu I want that the Manager class will know a button was pressed. I tried using flag that will indicate if a button was pressed, but it doesn't work for some reason. Here's my code:
 The gui class:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JFrame jframe;
private JPanel jpanel;
private JButton jbutton;
public boolean jbuttonFlag = false;
Gui(){

    jframe = new JFrame("Test Frame");

    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jpanel = new JPanel();

    jpanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    jbutton = new JButton("Click Me");

    jbutton.addActionListener(this);

    jpanel.add(jbutton);

    jframe.add(jpanel);

    jframe.pack();

    jframe.setVisible(true);
}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Click Me"))

                  jbuttonFlag = true;
    }
}
```

and the Manager class:

```
public class Manager{

    Gui g;

    Manager(){

        g = new Gui();

    }

    public void Start(){

        while( !g.jbuttonFlag );
        System.out.println("Button Pressed");

    }

}
```

When I click the button I want it to write in the console that it was clicked, however it doesn't happen. Why ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should synchronize them since they are separate threads. This worked for me:

In Manager:

```
public void Start(){

        synchronized(g){try{g.wait();}catch(Exception e){}}
        System.out.println("Button Pressed");

    }
```

In Gui:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Click Me")){
                synchronized(this){
                    this.notify();
                }
             }
    }
```

Comment: OK, thanks! Isn't using that while condition is also a sort of synchronization, because the while prevents from manager thread to move forward?

Comment: Another thing, what if I have different buttons, and I want different response for each button, I need to use synchronized for each button?

Comment: You can synchronize flag or other objects to determine which button is pressed. Just be sure that while one of the threads writes it the others should not try to read it. While is not a good solution since it keeps the cpu busy by making busy waiting. This may block your action listener and other threads.

Comment: You can read this tutorial for synchronizing: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm